# How to remove the pagination from the Print / PDF output of search results?

Tags: 7

I am displaying search results with 20 per page. I have total 100 results.

The print/pdf only display that 20 results in the pdf version and in print version.

I want to display all the results in print and in pdf?

How will I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either create another view of the search results to print, so when a user clicks print it either pops up a page or takes them to a new page with everything you want to see on the PDF.

Another option would be to expose a filter for the search that allows them to select the number of results displayed. Put a note on the page that says if they want to see all results on a PDF, to change the filter.

Comment: but the search page is not a view. it is simple the apache solr search page.

Comment: You are going to have to create a view to alter the results.